# Get password from input using node.js

Tags: input, node.js

How to get password from input using node.js? Which means you should not output password entered in console.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update **2015 Dec 13**: [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) has replaced `process.stdin` and [node_stdio was removed from Node 0.5.10](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/83fce75).

```
var BACKSPACE = String.fromCharCode(127);


// Probably should use readline
// https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html
function getPassword(prompt, callback) {
    if (prompt) {
      process.stdout.write(prompt);
    }

    var stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setRawMode(true);
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

    var password = '';
    stdin.on('data', function (ch) {
        ch = ch.toString('utf8');

        switch (ch) {
        case "\n":
        case "\r":
        case "\u0004":
            // They've finished typing their password
            process.stdout.write('\n');
            stdin.setRawMode(false);
            stdin.pause();
            callback(false, password);
            break;
        case "\u0003":
            // Ctrl-C
            callback(true);
            break;
        case BACKSPACE:
            password = password.slice(0, password.length - 1);
            process.stdout.clearLine();
            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
            process.stdout.write(prompt);
            process.stdout.write(password.split('').map(function () {
              return '*';
            }).join(''));
            break;
        default:
            // More passsword characters
            process.stdout.write('*');
            password += ch;
            break;
        }
    });
}

getPassword('Password: ', (ok, password) => { console.log([ok, password]) } );
```

Comment: You can't verify value. If you press backspace or other touch who isn't alphanumeric.

Comment: `require('tty').setRawMode()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 64):

You can use the [`read`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read) module *(disclosure: written by me)* for this:

In your shell:

```
npm install read
```

Then in your JS:

```
var read = require('read')
read({ prompt: 'Password: ', silent: true }, function(er, password) {
  console.log('Your password is: %s', password)
})
```

**UPDATE** modern version (using `await`):

```
const password = await read({
  prompt: "Password: ",
  silent: true,
  replace: "*" //optional, will print out an asterisk for every typed character 
};
console.log("Your password: " + password);
```

Comment: https://github.com/isaacs/read - Had some trouble googling for this module so, I'm dropping a link to it here for your convenience.

Comment: Is there a synchronous version?

Comment: @Mark: How could there be?  stdin is a stream and fires events.  Events cannot be processed if a function is waiting to return.

Comment: @josh3736: I don't know, perhaps in the same way that `readFileSync` works??

Comment: @josh3736: not sync, but I use module async.forEachSeries or async.forever to ask consecutive input questions via async functions.

Comment: when i try to debug a script that runs into this code I can't figure out what to type to let it actually enter my password

Comment: @isaacs - how do I setup the launch.json to provide the input args when debugging?

Comment: @mpen best workaround today to avoid the callback is to use `async`/`await` BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71868483/895245

Answer (score 5):

To do this I found this excellent [Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?lnk=raot&fwc=1#!topic/nodejs/K40kbz4J5gY)

Which contains the following snippet:

```
var stdin = process.openStdin()
  , stdio = process.binding("stdio")
stdio.setRawMode()

var password = ""
stdin.on("data", function (c) {
  c = c + ""
  switch (c) {
    case "\n": case "\r": case "\u0004":
      stdio.setRawMode(false)
      console.log("you entered: "+password)
      stdin.pause()
      break
    case "\u0003":
      process.exit()
      break
    default:
      password += c
      break
  }
})
```

Comment: Note process.binding("stdio") no longer works in current versions of node

Answer (score 4):

Here is my tweaked version of nailer's from above, updated to get a callback and for node 0.8 usage:

```
/**
 * Get a password from stdin.
 *
 * Adapted from <http://stackoverflow.com/a/10357818/122384>.
 *
 * @param prompt {String} Optional prompt. Default 'Password: '.
 * @param callback {Function} `function (cancelled, password)` where
 *      `cancelled` is true if the user aborted (Ctrl+C).
 *
 * Limitations: Not sure if backspace is handled properly.
 */
function getPassword(prompt, callback) {
    if (callback === undefined) {
        callback = prompt;
        prompt = undefined;
    }
    if (prompt === undefined) {
        prompt = 'Password: ';
    }
    if (prompt) {
        process.stdout.write(prompt);
    }

    var stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setRawMode(true);
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

    var password = '';
    stdin.on('data', function (ch) {
        ch = ch + "";

        switch (ch) {
        case "\n":
        case "\r":
        case "\u0004":
            // They've finished typing their password
            process.stdout.write('\n');
            stdin.setRawMode(false);
            stdin.pause();
            callback(false, password);
            break;
        case "\u0003":
            // Ctrl-C
            callback(true);
            break;
        default:
            // More passsword characters
            process.stdout.write('*');
            password += ch;
            break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can handle backspace with an extra case statement for `"u007F"`. If the password so far is non-empty, you can use `process.stdout.write('\033[<1>D')` to move the cursor back one column; after that you can write a space, then move back again.

Comment: I updated this to work with backspace and merged it with the original accepted answer and added a link to a repo that I plan to continue to improve.

Answer (score 2):

**How to use `read` without a callback**

With `async`/`await`, we can get rid of the annoying callback with the following standard pattern:

```
const readCb = require('read')

async function read(opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readCb(opts, (err, line) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(line)
      }
    })
  })
}

;(async () => {
  const password = await read({ prompt: 'Password: ', silent: true })
  console.log(password)
})()
```

The annoyance is that then you have to propagate async/await to the entire call stack, but it is generally the way to go, as it clearly marks what is async or not.

Tested on "read": "1.0.7", Node.js v14.17.0.

**TODO how to prevent EAGAIN error if you try to use stdin again later with `fs.readFileSync(0)`?**

Both `read` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357818/895245 cause future attempts to read from stdin with `fs.readFileSync(0)` to break with EAGAIN. Not sure how to fix that. Reproduction:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readCb = require('read')

async function read(opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readCb(opts, (err, line) => {
      resolve([err, line])
    })
  })
}

;(async () => {
  const [err, password] = await read({ prompt: 'Password: ', silent: true })
  console.log(password)
  console.log(fs.readFileSync(0).toString())
})()
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs')

var BACKSPACE = String.fromCharCode(127);

// Probably should use readline
// https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html
function getPassword(prompt, callback) {
    if (prompt) {
      process.stdout.write(prompt);
    }

    var stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setRawMode(true);
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

    var password = '';
    stdin.on('data', function (ch) {
        ch = ch.toString('utf8');

        switch (ch) {
        case "\n":
        case "\r":
        case "\u0004":
            // They've finished typing their password
            process.stdout.write('\n');
            stdin.setRawMode(false);
            stdin.pause();
            callback(false, password);
            break;
        case "\u0003":
            // Ctrl-C
            callback(true);
            break;
        case BACKSPACE:
            password = password.slice(0, password.length - 1);
            process.stdout.clearLine();
            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
            process.stdout.write(prompt);
            process.stdout.write(password.split('').map(function () {
              return '*';
            }).join(''));
            break;
        default:
            // More passsword characters
            process.stdout.write('*');
            password += ch;
            break;
        }
    });
}

async function read(opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getPassword(opts, (err, line) => {
      resolve([err, line])
    })
  })
}

;(async () => {
  const [err, password] = await read('Password: ')
  console.log(password)
  console.log(fs.readFileSync(0).toString())
})()
```

Error:

```
fs.js:614
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EAGAIN: resource temporarily unavailable, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:614:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:383:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:420:19)
    at /home/ciro/test/main.js:70:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  errno: -11,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EAGAIN'
}
```

Asked at: https://github.com/npm/read/issues/39

Comment: You could `reject()` if there's an error instead of returning a tuple. Your error might be from forgetting to close some pipe. e.g. you have to `close()` readline interfaces ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890409/65387))